# API between React JS and Oracle Databae

Tags: node.js, reactjs, oracle, api, oracle-rest-data-services

We have web reports built by invoking plsql strored-procedures which forms HTML document and pushed to UI using Oracle HTTP server. Its been decided to write web-reports UI in React JS. So, it needs APIs for acting as a bridge between React JS UI and Oracle DB.

My question is, what is the best way of implementing it?

- Can we use nodeJS to write APIs which get the data from DB and post it to React JS? or
- Can we use Oracle Rest Data Services(ORDS), which can directly be called by React JS?(Is it possible?) Or
  Please suggest if there is any better way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use NodeJS + express to write an API between your DB and React

Check that :

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-make-create-react-app-work-with-a-node-backend-api-7c5c48acb1b0/

Answer (score 0):

There is no 'best way' because it will depend on app requirements, architecture,  performance requirements, your tolerance of admin overhead of having either middle tier Node.js or having ORDS running, etc. etc. etc.

If you go the Node.js middle-tier route (which gives you most control), you would use [node-oracledb](https://www.npmjs.com/package/oracledb).

Comment: thank you. app requirement is to fetch cursor data from oracle stored procedures and display the same in UI components. All business logic are already written in database. So, if you help me with possible ways, i will try to find out the best way.